# add color to not selected range

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using JQuery Slider and I need to custom its css style, which is in the JQuery UI CSS Framework. I want the widget to have a background-color white (As it comes by default) and I've given to ui-slider-range a height of 30% to be a thin line and a top of 0.4em to be just in the middle of the widget content. I need that line to be red, so I've given red color to the ui-slider-range. But my issue is that I don't know how to make the color of the not selected range to be grey. I've been trying but I haven't figured out which is the class-name I have to modify to get that.

These are the class-names that affect to the slider

```
.ui-slider {
   position: relative;
   text-align: left;
   width: 400px;
 }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   width: 1.2em;
   height: 1.2em;
   cursor: default;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
   touch-action: none;
 }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   font-size: .7em;
   display: block;
   border: 0;
   background-position: 0 0;
 }

 /* support: IE8 - See #6727 */
.ui-slider.ui-state-disabled .ui-slider-handle,
.ui-slider.ui-state-disabled .ui-slider-range {
   filter: inherit;
 }

.ui-slider-horizontal {
   height: .8em;
 }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
   top: -.3em;
   margin-left: -.6em;
 }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range {
   top: 0.4em;
   height: 30%;
   background-color: red;
 }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
   left: 0;
 }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max {
   right: 0;
 }
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button {
   font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
   font-size: 1em;
 }
.ui-widget-content {
   border: 1px solid;
   background: #ffffff url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
   color: #222222;
 }
.ui-widget-content a {
   color: #222222;
 }
.ui-widget-header {
   border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
   background: #cccccc url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
   color: #222222;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
.ui-widget-header a {
    color: #222222;
 }
```

Edited:

This is the html code

```
<body>
  <p>
    <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>

  <div id="slider-range"></div>
</body>
```

And this the javascript code

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      animate: "fast",
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    var animate = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "option", "animate" );
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html for the slider?

Comment: Sure, I've just edited my question

Comment: It doesn't seem clear to me that what you're asking is possible without some really extensive work, or a different approach. One option might be to shrink the height of the .ui-slider-horizontal div? You may find something in [this article on border tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/)?

Comment: Yes I know that works but then the white background disappears..and I would like the white background to be there to contrast the layout behind

Comment: Well, the only other thing I can think of to try without rethinking the design would be to wrap the #slider-range div in another div which would have a  white background, and adjust the rest of your code around that. But you've probably already considered that angle. Sorry, maybe someone else has an answer.

Comment: Yes, finally I've decided to do that. I was trying to avoid it because I don't think is very clean but I don't want to waste more time with this. And it works well. So Thanks a lot @nthall